# How to fix "A Task was canceled" while uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to upload a log file from a desktop app client to the sql db server using webapi2 and im getting this error "A Task was canceled", this error does not appear when i host the webapi project on local machine though!

```
public static bool UploadLogData(string exceptionLog)
{
        bool result = true;


        string dataFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ExceptionLog.zip";

        CommonParamModel responseModel = new CommonParamModel();

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mywebsite.com") };
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "P1",  ComputerInfoHelper.GetCustomMachineKey())
                        , new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "P2", exceptionLog)
                    };

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            FileStream filestream = new FileStream(dataFilePath, FileMode.Open);
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dataFilePath);

            content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);
            content.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs));

            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            var response = httpClient.PostAsync("api/Users/AddExceptionDataLog/", content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string strResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(strResult);
                responseModel = json.ToObject(typeof(FreeUserApp)) as CommonParamModel;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.Error.LogException(Utilities.Error.ErrorSources.Exception, ex.Message, Utilities.Debugger.GetCurrentMethod(), ex);
            result = false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Side note : You are mixing `async` and synchronous code, dont do that

Comment: Also, be sure to await those async calls.  This may be your problem.

Comment: hmm, but i'm calling the Result after async so basically its a sync call... am i correct?

Comment: Calling `Result` actually blocks the thread until the call completes.  Using `await` instead will free up the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Michael Randall** and **DBro** It actually worked, the problem was solved after using await on client and on the api method...